# Crankset specs for 2013 gt backwoods sport

Tags: shimano, crankset, threaded-bottom-bracket

I have a 2013-2014 GT Backwoods sport 27.5 bike that needs a crankset replacement.

I removed today the crankset and see that the crankset has splines that seem to match the splines that are part of the Tapered square English bottom bracket. I had bought a new Shimano crankset from Amazon and although it supported the English bottom bracket is did not have the splines as the original one.

Do cranksets need these splines or can I go ahead and install a crankset that matches the English bottom bracket but has no splines?

[image: bottom bracket photo]
[image: crankset, see splines at the end green arrows]

Comment: Welcome to the site - thank you for asking a well-illustrated and described question straight up.  That's definitely appreciated and surprisingly uncommon for first-time askers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fine to install the new one - the crank/spider is secured to the bottom bracket spindle by the square taper.

The marks you're seeing would prevent the cranks from rotating if they meshed with the lands and valleys on the bike.   Which is not possible because both sets are on the inside - to get interaction between them, one would have to be on the outside (ie, one pointing toward center of spindle and one pointing away from spindle centerline.)

What you're seeing on the inside of the cranks/spider is probably a manufacturing process that coincidentally resembles the splines inside the drive-side cup of your bottom bracket.

Comment: Got it, I see, good point, thank you.